# Sql Server: Comma separated column values exist in other comma separated column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a table

```
OrgData
OrgDataid  columvalues
1          1,2,3,4,5
2          6,7,8,9
3          16,17,18,19
```

Another table holds selected values

```
selectedData
rowid   sid   orgid   values
1       1     1       1,2
2       1     2       6,7,8,9
3       2     1       1,2,3,4,5
```

Where sid is the id of OrgData

I want output like

for sid 1;

```
outputData
OrgData   columvalues
1         partial selected
2         Full selected
3         Nothing selected
```

I want some straightway query, while I am trying to do it with splitting every comma separated to rows and looping for each one.

Thanks

Comment: Fix you data structure.  Storing values in comma-delimited strings is the wrong way to store values in a relational database.

Comment: this is already there, so I am not allowed to change it

Comment: have you told them that there is a serious flaw in their database design that will only get them into more trouble in the future ? And that all you can do now is build a bad workaround that will surely fail one day

Comment: You need a splitter and relational division. Whichof them  is a problem exactly?

Comment: Question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this:

--*mock-up-tables* with your data

```
DECLARE @OrgData TABLE(OrgDataid INT,columvalues VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @OrgData VALUES
 (1,'1,2,3,4,5')
,(2,'6,7,8,9')
,(3,'16,17,18,19');

DECLARE @selectedData TABLE(rowid INT,[sid] INT,orgid INT,[values] VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @selectedData VALUES
 (1,1,1,'1,2')
,(2,1,2,'6,7,8,9')
,(3,2,1,'1,2,3,4,5');
```

--First CTE to split OrgData

```
WITH OrgDataSplitted AS
(
    SELECT od.*
          ,LEN(od.columvalues)-LEN(REPLACE(od.columvalues,',',''))+1 AS CountParts
          ,B.Part.value('.','int') AS PartInt
    FROM @OrgData AS od
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(columvalues,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) AS A(Casted)
    CROSS APPLY A.Casted.nodes('/x') AS B(Part)
)
```

--Second CTE to split SelectedData

```
,SelectedSplitted AS
(
    SELECT sd.*
          ,B.Part.value('.','int') AS PartInt
    FROM @selectedData AS sd
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE([values],',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) AS A(Casted)
    CROSS APPLY A.Casted.nodes('/x') AS B(Part)
)
```

--The query to join them

```
SELECT o.OrgDataid,o.CountParts,s.rowid,COUNT(rowid) AS CountIdent
FROM Orgdatasplitted AS o
FULL OUTER JOIN SelectedSplitted AS s ON o.OrgDataID=s.orgid and o.PartInt=s.PartInt
GROUP BY o.OrgDataid,o.CountParts,s.rowid
ORDER BY o.OrgDataid
```

The result. If CountParts and CountIdent is the *same* it's full, >0 is *partial* and 0 is *none*

```
+-----------+------------+-------+------------+
| OrgDataid | CountParts | rowid | CountIdent |
+-----------+------------+-------+------------+
| 1         | 5          | 1     | 2          |
+-----------+------------+-------+------------+
| 1         | 5          | 3     | 5          |
+-----------+------------+-------+------------+
| 2         | 4          | 2     | 4          |
+-----------+------------+-------+------------+
| 3         | 4          | NULL  | 0          |
+-----------+------------+-------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below script, may be help you. But I agree with @Gordon Linoff, 
Fix you data structure. Storing values in comma-delimited strings is the wrong way.

```
SELECT  OrgDataid
        ,(CASE  WHEN OD.columvalues = SD.[values] THEN 'Full selected'
                WHEN SD.rowid IS NULL THEN 'Nothing selected'
         ELSE 'partial selected' END) AS columvalues
FROM    OrgData AS  OD
LEFT OUTER JOIN selectedData AS SD ON OD.columvalues LIKE '%'+SD.[values]+'%'
```

Comment: it's not fix that continuous value will be selected, it may select any value